# Error merging rasters in QGIS

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, merge

I use QGIS 3.4. I would like to merge 2 rasters (.TIF) (using Raster-Miscellaneous-Merge) that contain elevation data. Unfortunately, I always get the error message:

> The following layers were not correctly generated.

I attach a screenshot of the log. I already checked that the files are in their correct place and played around with some of the options.

Unfortunately nothing worked. The files are enormous in size

Would this be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Your QGIS installation has some problem. The error is "gdal_merge.py: command not found". It must be found for using it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I reinstalled QGIS and the merge was actually executed, but still it is faulty. Instead of getting a properly merged picture I get only a black map. Any suggestion about what I might have done wrong?

Comment: have you solved your problem? I'm in the same situation and already tried everything I knew...

Comment: No I haven't unfortunately. Would be glad if you posted your solution ...in case there is one!